# Netbeans new project window is empty

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

I installed NetBeans 8.0.2 in my Windows 10 x64 machine. installation is completed and after open NetBeans, I tried to create a new project by file->new project after I got new project wizard. but I didn't see any project types or file folders in here. it's just a 2 white boxes. I tried reinstalling but same issue happens to me and I never faced to issue like this. Any idea guys?

Answer (score 1):

Try http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-netbeans-jsp-142931.html  to download ntbeans and JDK that are compatible.

Comment: I have upgraded the netbeans version. Issue was fixed. Thanks.